# call web url multiple times in asp.net.cx

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, web-services, web

I am trying to call a web URL which contain parameters `lat` and `long`, and I want to call that web page multiple times until the asp application closes.

I am recieving the values whenever the aspx page is loaded but for getting updated values I have to refresh the page to call the `page_Load` function again and again.

What I want is to get values from the url again and again without refreshing the aspx page.

```
//my code of my aspx.cs file

public partial class locationtesting : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  public string longit, lat;
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string downloadedString = client.DownloadString("url.php");
        string[] tokens = downloadedString.Split(':');
        string longitude = tokens[1];
        string latitude = tokens[3];

        this.longit = longitude;
        this.lat = latitude;

    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        Response.Write("Exception: "+ee);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the asp.net page do other things?  Do you have to use an asp.net page?  Have you considered implementing client/ajax calls to trigger the subsequent calls so the page does not have to be refreshed? Could you use a console app or windows service instead for this?

Comment: The asp page consists of many other things, just as a map which is loaded online and some text fields and paragraph's , and yes i have to use asp.net page. and i don't have good idea of ajax calls. kindly share some example regarding such solution.